# Count values separated by a comma in a character string

Tags: r, vector, character

I have this example data

```
d<-"30,3"
class(d)
```

I have this character objects in one column in my work data frame and I need to be able to identify how many numbers it has.

I have tried to use `length(d)`, but it says 1

After looking for solution here I have tried

```
eval(parse(text='d'))
as.numeric(d)
as.vector.character(d)
```

But it still doesn't work.

Any straightforward approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably `as.numeric(strsplit(d, ",")[[1]])`. If you know how many numbers you have there, you could try `length(strsplit(d, ",")[[1]])`

Comment: Great, it works. I know how many numbers I have there and need to select the right 'group' of them. Thank you a lot

Comment: And what if d<-as.factor(30,3") ? I see now factor in another column.

Comment: `as.factor` won't separate them

Comment: If you want to use `eval` + `parse` you need to give it `"c(30, 3)"` as input. So `eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", d, ")")))`

Comment: Note: use eval + parse is much much faster than strsplit, it seems it is more than 10x faster, especially when the object is big like in my case (3Gb). Thank you for that

Comment: NOTE2: Not 10x faster, but more than 100x faster.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These two approaches are each short, work on vectors of strings, do not involve the expense of explicitly constructing the split string and do not use any packages.  Here `d` is a vector of strings such as `d <- c("1,2,3", "5,2")` :

**1) count.fields**

```
count.fields(textConnection(d), sep = ",")
```

**2) gregexpr**

```
lengths(gregexpr(",", d)) + 1
```

Answer (score 20):

You could use `scan`.

```
 v1 <- scan(text=d, sep=',', what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
 v1
 #[1] 30  3
```

Or using `stri_split` from `stringi`.  This should take both `character` and `factor` class without converting explicitly to character using `as.character`

```
library(stringi)
v2 <- as.numeric(unlist(stri_split(d,fixed=',')))
v2
#[1] 30  3
```

You can do the `count` using `base R` by

```
length(v1)
#[1] 2
```

Or

```
nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', d))+1
#[1] 2
```

Visualize the `regex`

```
 [^,]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/myi9jTntK546MhBn)

#### Update

If `d` is a column in a dataset `df` and want to subset rows with number of digits equals `2`

```
  d<-c("30,3,5","30,5") 
  df <- data.frame(d,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df[nchar(gsub('[^,]', '',df$d))+1==2,,drop=FALSE]
  #    d
  #2 30,5
```

Just to test

```
  df[nchar(gsub('[^,]', '',df$d))+1==10,,drop=FALSE]
  #[1] d
  #<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thank you and what if d<-as.factor("30,3")?

Comment: Convert it to character firts works with one example, but when I have more data like d<-c("30,3,5","30,5") and I need to "subset" like show me only these from d with 2 numbers I cannot deal with it. Sorry for a bit complicated question

Comment: Real data is a big data frame, where one column are factors like "30,3,5","30,5" and so. And I need to subset this data frame like df[length(df$d)==2,] in simple way to see only these rows where there are only 2 numbers in column d (the one with factors). More clear?

Comment: @Bury Yes, that is easy with the `df[nchar(gsub('^,]', '',df$d))+1==2,]`

Comment: Sorry, I have to take it back. This is not right solution. I column d I have only 2 or 3 numbers in it, but with your solution it gives me some subset even if I give it df[nchar(gsub('^,]', '',df$d))+1==10,] which is nonsense

Comment: @Bury, I might have missed a `[`.  Try with the updated one in the post. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

You could also try `stringi` package `stri_count_*` funcitons (should be very effcient)

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_regex(d, "\\d+")
## [1] 2
stri_count_fixed(d, ",") + 1
## [1] 2
```

`stringr` package has a similar functionality

```
library(stringr)
str_count(d, "\\d+")
## [1] 2
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to subset your data set by length 2 vectors, could try

```
df[stri_count_regex(df$d, "\\d+") == 2,, drop = FALSE]
#      d
# 2 30,5
```

Or simpler

```
subset(df, stri_count_regex(d, "\\d+") == 2)
#      d
# 2 30,5
```

---

**Update #2**

Here's a benchmark that illustrates why one *should* consider using external packages (@rengis answer wasn't included because it doesn't answer the question)

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(stringi)
d <- rep("30,3", 1e4)

microbenchmark( akrun = nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', d))+1,
                GG1 = count.fields(textConnection(d), sep = ","),
                GG2 = sapply(gregexpr(",", d), length) + 1,
                DA1 = stri_count_regex(d, "\\d+"),
                DA2 = stri_count_fixed(d, ",") + 1)

# Unit: microseconds
#  expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
# akrun  8817.950  9479.9485 11489.7282 10642.4895 12480.845  46538.39   100
#   GG1 55451.474 61906.2460 72324.0820 68783.9935 78980.216 150673.72   100
#   GG2 33026.455 43349.5900 60960.8762 51825.6845 72293.923 203126.27   100
#   DA1  4730.302  5120.5145  6206.8297  5550.7930  7179.536  10507.09   100
#   DA2   380.147   418.2395   534.6911   448.2405   597.259   2278.11   100
```

Comment: +1 on the fast alternatives, but I think some of these also need to be modified. For example, test with `x <- c("a,b,c", "a", "", "a,b")`. You'll need something like: `temp <- stri_count_fixed(x, ",") + 1; ind <- which(x == ""); temp[ind] <- 0; temp `

Comment: @AnandaMahto hmm, man this is so old that I have no idea what's this question even about... I'll see if I'll have some time to check what you have mentioned. Or maybe you"ll just edit it?

Comment: It's just the difference in behavior of `count.fields` with empty lines in comparison to searching across a character string. Not likely relevant to *this* question, but might throw someone off if they were expecting a zero for the third element in "x" above.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a possibility

```
> as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("30,3", ",")))
# 30  3
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on the accepted answer, requires no packages. Using the example `d <- c("1,2,3", "5,2")`

```
lengths(strsplit(d, ","))

> [1] 3 2
```

Or as a `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(d = d)

df$counts <- lengths(strsplit(df$d, ","))

df

#----
    d counts
1,2,3      3
  5,2      2
```