# How to count multiple text values in a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column of city names, in each cell of this column there are multiple text values separated by `","`.

For example the first 4 rows of the cities column of my df are:

```
"Barcelona, Milaan, Londen, Paris, Berlin"
"Barcelona"
"Milaan, Barcelona, Berlin"
"London, Berlin"
```

I want to count for each row of this column 
wheter these cities occurs.

For example, the output needs to look like this:

```
count_cities

    5
    1
    3
    2
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you had a look at this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599535/count-values-separated-by-a-comma-in-a-character-string

Comment: @Peter, yes thank you. Unfortunately, it does not work for me..

Comment: What did you try so far? And what were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATA:

```
cities <- data.frame(names = c("Barcelona, Milaan, Londen, Paris, Berlin","Barcelona",
            "Milaan, Barcelona, Berlin","London, Berlin"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

To count how many city `names`there are you can first split the string at `,`and count the splits using `lengths`:

```
cities$count <- lengths(strsplit(cities$names, ","))
```

The resulting dataframe is this:

```
cities
                                     names count
1 Barcelona, Milaan, Londen, Paris, Berlin     5
2                                Barcelona     1
3                Milaan, Barcelona, Berlin     3
4                           London, Berlin     2
```

**EDIT**:

If the strings contain not only city `names`but additional information, you can use `str_count`to match upper-case letters (because city names begin with an upper-case letter but other words don't, at least not in the example you've given):

```
cities <- data.frame(names = c("Barcelona, Milaan, Londen, Paris, Berlin","Barcelona (a big city)",
            "Milaan, Barcelona, Berlin","London, Berlin (are all capitals, are big cities)"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(stringr)
cities$count <- str_count(cities$names, "[A-Z][a-z]+")
```

Alternatively, use `str_extract`:

```
cities$count <- lengths(str_extract_all(cities$names, "[A-Z][a-z]+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
travel <- tibble(CITYS = c("Barcelona, Milaan, Londen, Paris, Berlin",
                            "Barcelona",
                            "Milaan, Barcelona, Berlin",
                            "London, Berlin"))
travel %>% 
  mutate(CITY.COUNT = map_dbl(str_split(CITYS, ",\\s*"), length))
```

Yields

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  CITYS                                    CITY.COUNT
  <chr>                                         <dbl>
1 Barcelona, Milaan, Londen, Paris, Berlin          5
2 Barcelona                                         1
3 Milaan, Barcelona, Berlin                         3
4 London, Berlin                                    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(travel$CITYS, "\\w+")
#[1] 5 1 3 2
```