# How to tally elements in a cell

Tags: r

(I am using r Studio)

I am doing a lit review where I record gene variants and then record the paper ID from which the variant was recorded from. I want to be able to count the number of papers each variant has like a tally:

For example
in the first row of column PMID, there are 4 papers, so I want my output for that specific cell to be 4, and for the next cell below to be 5, and below that to be 3.

If anyone could help with that'd be greatly appreciated!

Dataframe "gene" column "Pmid"
[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. You have a higher chance of being helped if you post a small reproducible example and the code you have already tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count values separated by a comma in a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599535/count-values-separated-by-a-comma-in-a-character-string)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strsplit` and `lengths`

```
df <- data.frame(PMID = c("258,234,212", "234,235,256,265"))

df$counts <- lengths(strsplit(df$PMID, ","))

df

#-----
             PMID counts
1     258,234,212      3
2 234,235,256,265      4
```