# Count strings either side of character ";"

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe which contains a column that looks like:

```
df<-data.frame(x=runif(24),value=rep(c("B","C;D",NA,"CG;M;Bac","GCP;Coag+","GCP;CNS"),each=4))
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences of any string either side of a ";" in each row. Note not all rows contain ";" (could be a single entry or a NA). So the output would look like:

```
1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2
```

for the above.

This works if I know what all the possible strings could be:

```
df %>%
mutate(stC = stringr::str_count(value, regex('dips|GNB|B|Bac|M', ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

But often the data is not homogeneous across files and so that regex doesn't capture everything.

I can't just count ";" as I can't differentiate between a NA and a single entry. Any thoughts would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps some answers here are relevant: [Count values separated by a comma in a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599535/count-values-separated-by-a-comma-in-a-character-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strsplit`:

```
sapply(strsplit(df$value, split = ";"), FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))

# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

If you want to keep this within a data manipulation piping process:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(count = sum(!is.na(unlist(str_split(value, ";")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick via `gsub` + `nchar`

```
transform(
  df,
  stC = nchar(gsub("[^;]", "", value)) + 1
)
```

which gives

```
            x     value stC
1  0.07071245         B   1
2  0.57201489         B   1
3  0.21928640         B   1
4  0.24782731         B   1
5  0.54730194       C;D   2
6  0.11669014       C;D   2
7  0.39478743       C;D   2
8  0.90583778       C;D   2
9  0.23873492      <NA>  NA
10 0.88155678      <NA>  NA
11 0.34854135      <NA>  NA
12 0.70870930      <NA>  NA
13 0.51896957  CG;M;Bac   3
14 0.53956594  CG;M;Bac   3
15 0.55756380  CG;M;Bac   3
16 0.23305755  CG;M;Bac   3
17 0.01511163 GCP;Coag+   2
18 0.38403218 GCP;Coag+   2
19 0.25471746 GCP;Coag+   2
20 0.18228425 GCP;Coag+   2
21 0.40186797   GCP;CNS   2
22 0.73385147   GCP;CNS   2
23 0.01230535   GCP;CNS   2
24 0.83073539   GCP;CNS   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach.

Note:

- `str_count` is used to count the number of matches in the string `;`.
- `+1` is used because, given your data, the count will always be one more than the number of pattern matches.
- `replace_na` is used to replace `NA` in `stC` with `0`.

```r
df<-data.frame(x=runif(24),value=rep(c("B","C;D",NA,"CG;M;Bac","GCP;Coag+","GCP;CNS"),each=4))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    stC = stringr::str_count(value, ';') + 1,
    stC = tidyr::replace_na(stC, 0)
  )

#>             x     value   stC
#> 1  0.88706780         B     1
#> 2  0.07799586         B     1
#> 3  0.46904607         B     1
#> 4  0.82041905         B     1
#> 5  0.23627374       C;D     2
#> 6  0.56468751       C;D     2
#> 7  0.42610653       C;D     2
#> 8  0.54008977       C;D     2
#> 9  0.01811806      <NA>     0
#> 10 0.89693212      <NA>     0
#> 11 0.84679765      <NA>     0
#> 12 0.10942276      <NA>     0
#> 13 0.08499520  CG;M;Bac     3
#> 14 0.53090536  CG;M;Bac     3
#> 15 0.05778523  CG;M;Bac     3
#> 16 0.41714664  CG;M;Bac     3
#> 17 0.46357215 GCP;Coag+     2
#> 18 0.77451204 GCP;Coag+     2
#> 19 0.77849339 GCP;Coag+     2
#> 20 0.39174393 GCP;Coag+     2
#> 21 0.53444433   GCP;CNS     2
#> 22 0.80431627   GCP;CNS     2
#> 23 0.02675931   GCP;CNS     2
#> 24 0.63962421   GCP;CNS     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>