# How to calculate the number of elements in a string for each observation

Tags: r, string

Here is a representation of my dataset

```
mydata<-data.frame(ID=1:3, str=c("ANN_ABL_ABL","ABL", "SLE_ANN"))
```

I want to calculate the number of elements in the string of each observation, in order to have a dataset like below.

```
  ID         str number_of_elements
1  1 ANN_ABL_ABL                  3
2  2         ABL                  1
3  3     SLE_ANN                  2
```

Comment: Try perhaps `mydata$number_of_elements <- lengths(strsplit(mydata$str, "_"))`

Comment: There's a bunch of options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27599535/5325862) for which you can swap the comma for an underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, using `stringr::str_count`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata<-data.frame(ID=1:3, str=c("ANN_ABL_ABL","ABL", "SLE_ANN"))

mydata %>% 
  mutate(n = str_count(str, "_") + 1)

#>   ID         str n
#> 1  1 ANN_ABL_ABL 3
#> 2  2         ABL 1
#> 3  3     SLE_ANN 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The `scan` function is set up to pull apart lines of text. It's default first parameter is a file name but a `text` parameter was added a couple of years ago. You can cook up an identical function whose first parameter is `text` and I also chose to make the default for the expected type of input to be "character".

```
scant <- function(txt, ...){scan(text=txt, what="", quiet=TRUE, ...) }
```

I went through those gymnastics to allow the `scan*` function to work within an `lapply` call:

```
lengths( lapply(mydata$str, scant, sep="_") )
```

I could have used an anonymous, throwaway function to do this in one line, but I decided instead to put this helper function in my .Rprofile setup. For many years I had a somewhat similar `read.txt` function that used a `textConnection` to supply character data to the `read.table` function. It became unnecessary when the text parameter was added to `scan`.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
transform(
  mydata,
  number_of_elements = nchar(gsub("[^_]","",str))+1
)
```

gives

```
  ID         str number_of_elements
1  1 ANN_ABL_ABL                  3
2  2         ABL                  1
3  3     SLE_ANN                  2
```